# Publish stored procedure from SQL Server Project selectively depending on the server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I have an SQL Server Project as a part of my solution in Visual Studio. It requires that I include some stored procedures that access a different database on the same server. This database is not under our control, nor is it accessible locally to the developers, or in our dev Server. And we cannot import that database because its a few TB in size. The functionality represented by this stored procedures does not need to be called in our dev environment, and only has testable data in the staging and production environments where the other database is accessible.

When we attempt to publish the project to our dev servers, or locally, the publish script generated by VS fails at run time because SQL Server can't generate a stored procedure if it can't resolve the references to the missing database.

I am looking for a way to setup the publishing so that it is selective based on the @@servername variable (ideally, but I am open to other realistic scenarios, such as a way to tell the SQL Server not to try to resolve those references)

Thanks

P.S. I hadnt thought of mentioning it until @larnu's comment, but an additional thorn here is that our dev environment is hosted as an Azure Web app and using an Azure SQL Database server. Even if I created a Mock database for the missing reference, Azure SQL will not allow my stored procedures to see them.

Comment: Recreate the parts you need in your Dev database. A dev database doesn't need all the data your production one has, certainly none of the client data will be in it just "test" clients, so they are often trivial in size in comparison.

Comment: I would but our dev environment is using Azure SQL so the databases still wouldn't be able to talk to each other. The client's staging and production environment have full sql servers.

Comment: It seems like your Dev environement isn't fit for purpose then. Though, most of the time, the Dev environment and instance are local, not in Azure. It doesn't make sense to have your Dev databases in Azure. Especially an Azure SQL Database; which are nothing alike a SQL Server Instance.